# delete multiple characers between separator with regular expressions

Tags: regex

I have a string like "some_{abcd_etc}_text"
eveything between { } should be removed, including {} itself.
I need only the string "some_text" at the end.
How can this been done by regex?

Comment: Deleting everything between and including the braces would leave you with "some__text" with two underscores, not one. I don't know if you want to take that into account or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this expression:

```
{.*?}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just replace this with an empty string:

> `{[^}]+}`

Here is a Python example:

```
>>> from re import sub
>>> s = r'some_{abcd_etc}_text'
>>> sub(r'{[^}]+}', '', s)
'some__text'
```